# Extra spaces in rust doc comment gets interpreted as doc test

Tags: rust

It appears that if I leave a blank line in a doc comment followed by an indentation of 4 spaces then cargo interprets it as a doc test and gives me a fail when I run cargo test.  What should I know about doc comments and tests that explains this?

Here's some example code that is in lib.rs:

```
/// This is a great function.
/// y: a very dangerous option.
///
///     note: Use None for y or you'll be sorry.
pub fn thing(x: i32, y: Option<i32>) -> i32 {
    if y.is_some() {
        println!("explode!");
    }
    x
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_thing() {
        assert_eq!(thing(5, None), 5);
    }
}
```

If I run cargo test, here is the output:

```
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running unittests (target/debug/deps/test_docs-28c699ad5df73c48)

running 1 test
test tests::test_thing ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

   Doc-tests test_docs

running 1 test
test src/lib.rs - thing (line 5) ... FAILED

failures:

---- src/lib.rs - thing (line 5) stdout ----
error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `.`, `::`, `;`, `<`, `?`, or `}`, found `None`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:11
  |
3 | note: Use None for y or you'll be sorry.
  |     -     ^^^^ expected one of 8 possible tokens
  |     |
  |     tried to parse a type due to this

error: aborting due to previous error

Couldn't compile the test.

failures:
    src/lib.rs - thing (line 5)

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.03s

error: test failed, to rerun pass '--doc'
```

If I remove a single space from the indentation before 'note' in the doc comment, then everything works as expected:

```
/// This is a great function.
/// y: a very dangerous option.
///
///    note: Use None for y or you'll be sorry.
pub fn thing(x: i32, y: Option<i32>) -> i32 {
    if y.is_some() {
        println!("explode!");
    }
    x
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_thing() {
        assert_eq!(thing(5, None), 5);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Compiling test_docs v0.1.0 (/Users/cleverpiggy/test_docs)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.34s
     Running unittests (target/debug/deps/test_docs-28c699ad5df73c48)

running 1 test
test tests::test_thing ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

   Doc-tests test_docs

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indentation with 4 spaces is equivalent to surrounding with backticks - more information can be found at [the syntax reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#syntax-reference)